# Get index of imported row (datatable.ImportRows())

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

Is there a way to return the index for an imported row using datatable.ImportRows?

I want to copy a datarow to the same datatable, so purposley duplicate a row (which i will modify when i get the index).

```
System.Data.DataTable test;
test.importRows(datarow);
```

Answer (score 3):

The new row will be added to the end of the data table. So the index will be `test.Rows.Count-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Taking from [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx):

> You can get the index of the new row with as DataTable.Rows.Find and
>   DataTable.Rows.IndexOf.

For example:

```
int rowIndex = test.Rows.IndexOf(datarow);
```

---

If a new row is being added (as you suggest by duplicating the row) then it will get added to the end of the current collection, so you can count the rows and subtract one:

```
int rowIndex = test.Rows.Count - 1;
```

Comment: I suppose the test.Rows.Count - 1; will have to do because i'm not sure the other method will work if you are copying the same row to the same datatable.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Data.DataTable test;
test.importRows(datarow);    
test.Rows.IndexOf(datarow);
```

Comment: Hello Sorry, if i'm copying it to the same datatable (so i duplicate the row purposley)